# Replacement for TypeLibFunc in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard, typelib

I'm trying to uplift some older .NET Framework code to .NET Standard 2.0.

```
[TypeLibFunc(TypeLibFuncFlags.FRestricted)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
void InitNew([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=1)] byte[] _rgb, int cb);
```

TypeLibFunc doesn't exist here. Is it still valid, and is there a replacement/substitute for it? I see a [TYPEFLAGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.typeflags?view=netstandard-2.0) enum but don't see a way to apply it. I would like to avoid Std 2.1, as it loses compatibility with Framework.

Comment: It's not available in .NET standard 2.0. Only in .NET Standard 2.1, .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5/6/... [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.typelibfuncattribute#applies-to)

Comment: Right, thanks. Because it's a library consumed by Framework code, I am going to Standard 2.0, and I'm wondering if they provide something different, e.g. something that uses `TYPEFLAGS`, or if support is simply not present.

Comment: You could manually add the attribute, by copying the code from [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/attributes.cs#L360). But I don't know if there are any guarantees it's properly used by the interop handler.

Comment: It is auto-generated code, produced by Tlbimp.exe to create an interop assembly.  Notable is that using Project > Add COM Reference does *not* produce [TypeLibFunc], the CLR doesn't use the attribute and it is therefore not critical to proper operation.  I have yet to see a practical application of it.  Tlbimp is no longer supported in .NETCore, using Add COM Reference is the right way to move ahead.